# Problem trying to configure USB debugging from android phone: Device is not recognized

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I'm having Samsung Galaxy I9003 phone and I want to debug my android app from the device.

I'm using Windows 7 - 32 bit

I have installed USB driver but when I connect my device to computer, it is not recognized.

I trying to update the installer through Computer->Manage, it is saying the best driver is already installed.

When I run "adb devices" command, it is showing "List of devices attached" but nothing listed down.

Any help in this regard is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tick usb debuggin in device ?

Comment: I dont think it would be the case but have you installed Kies?

Comment: If it is a Galaxy S with a stock Android ROM/firmware from Samsung, you wil need to have KIES installed. KIES will install its own USB drivers for connectiong to the SGS. I had the same issue with my SGS I900. Installing KIES fixed it. You can still have the windows android driver installed to debug other devices.

Answer (score 0):

try enabling USB debugging mode by going to Menu>Settings>Applications>Development>USB Debugging and then connect

Comment: yes.I enabled the USB debugging,now  It is working fine . thank you.